# Facebook Open Graph story inconsistently showing in the share dialog

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created an open graph story in Facebook, it is live, approved, sandbox mode off.

When I post with an account that is an admin of the facebook app it works perfectly.

When I post with a test account the story ("James ate at a restaurant via MyApp") does not show in the share dialog and it fails.

I did a log of the permissions of both users and they are exactly the same. I am sharing the same information to facebook in both cases. I am on the latest version of iOS and FacebookSDK.

Below are some code snippets that I thought might be relevant.

```
id<FBOpenGraphAction> action = (id<FBOpenGraphAction>)[FBGraphObject graphObject];
id object = [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPostWithType:@"restaurant.restaurant"
                                                    title:_postParams[@"name"]
                                                    image:_postParams[@"picture"]
                                                      url:_postParams[@"link"]
                                              description:_postParams[@"description"]];


action[@"restaurant"] = object;

[FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithOpenGraphAction:action actionType:@"myapp:eat"
    previewPropertyName:@"restaurant"
    handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
        // handle the result
    }];
```

Thanks for reading, any help or debugging techniques would be much appreciated. Let me know what other code I can provide to make the question easier to answer. I understand it may be a bit vague but I am hoping someone has experienced the same thing.

Comment: I just noticed that my app object has been submitted and approved but not my action type. I am awaiting a response from Facebook but I think its quite possible this is the issue. I will post the results soon.

Comment: I can confirm this was the issue.